# Async Threads Not Released

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm having trouble with an Async method in C#/.NET 4. It adds threads to the w3wp process, but doesn't release them.  Our server eventually reaches a thread limit around 400, and then the app pool becomes unreachable while it recycles.

Are we using EndInvoke wrong here?

Here's a simplified example that repros the problem:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        TestFind("test");
    }

    private delegate void TestFindDelegate(String val);
    private TestFindDelegate tfd;
    private IAsyncResult iar;

    public void TestFind(String val)
    {
        try
        {
            tfd = new TestFindDelegate(this.TestFindAsync);
            iar = tfd.BeginInvoke(val, null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    //Method runs asynchronously
    private void TestFindAsync(String val)
    {            
        try
        {
            //Run stuff here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String msg = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            tfd.EndInvoke(iar); //clean up resources
        }
    }
```

**Steps to Repro:** 
 1. Add code above into a web service.asmx 
 2. Open Task Manager, add column Threads, find process 
 3. Open Fiddler, go to Composer, and enter web service url/Test 
 4. Click Execute 20-40 times 
 5. Watch the thread count on the process increase, but not decrease.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually getting through `//Run stuff here` ?

Comment: Yeah, this code repros the issue as is, even with nothing in //Run stuff here.

Comment: You are indeed doing it wrong, EndInvoke() must be called *after* the method stops running.  The 3rd argument to BeginInvoke() lets you pass a delegate to the completion callback, call EndInvoke in that callback.

Comment: If you would like to post a solution post it as *an answer* rather than as an edit to the question.  The question should just contain the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're not calling `EndInvoke` properly.  When using `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, you must always call `EndInvoke`, and you must call it *after* your method is completed.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx):

> No matter which technique you use, always call EndInvoke to complete your asynchronous call.

Right now, you're keeping track of `tfd` and `iar` in a variable, but each call will overwrite that variable.  As such, if you call this 100 times quickly, you'll only call `EndInvoke` once.

A better option would be to just use `Task` to run this:

```
public void TestFind(String val)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.TestFindAsync(val));
}
```

This will call this on a threadpool thread, but not require the `EndInvoke` call, or any of the local variables to be saved.

Comment: EndInvoke is being reached in the finally block above when I step through it.  Each call overwrites the global vars?

Comment: @user2378631 Yes - but it's not going to be called on every instance of `tfd`/`iar` if you're calling again before the first async operation completes.

Comment: @user2378631 It also needs to happen AFTER the method is completed.  This would mean, in your current architecture, you'd need to also supply a callback, and call EndInvoke in that callback, not in the method itself.

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate your insight, and alternative code suggestion.  For the sake of learning, and to provide a resource to others who might visit this question, how could we rework the code above to work correctly?  Do we just need to pass variables in, instead of setting globally outside the methods?

Comment: @user2378631 See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx  Look at the section on using a callback method - that's what you'd need to do.

Comment: That seems to work, thank you!  I added the working solution, let me know if you see any possible issues with it.  Thanks again for your help!